# Symfony panther issue

Tags: php, symfony, google-chrome, web-scraping, symfony-panther

I am using Symfony Panther for web scraping. When Google Chrome's  version and Chrome driver was 89, everything worked fine. But after updating both versions to 92,

`$crawler->filter('h1')->html();`

will always return empty string.

I think, the problem is related to this method `>html()`

Could you please let me know  if you have a solution for this.

Comment: Can you update your question with some example code? I couldn't reproduce this error.

Comment: I think structure of crawled page is changed

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles onto this issue, I ran into this same problem and found a workaround by getting the first element from the crawler selector then the outerHTML property.  Some say innerHTML works but that came up blank.

```
$crawler->filter( 'h1')->getElement(0)->getDomProperty('outerHTML');
```